# Is there a specific term for sentences written with symbols or emoji only?

Tags: phrases, expressions, symbols

Is there a specific term for sentences written with symbols or emoji only instead of words? An example would be a string of emoji on a facebook comment of a post.

Comment: Perhaps a *neo-rebus*?

Comment: how about semiotical diarrhea?

Comment: I'd use "unintelligible", if I knew how to spell it.

Answer (score 3):

Not exact but close enough,see **ideography**.

[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ideography)

> The use of ideograms ([see definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideogram))  or logograms ([see definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logogram))  to express ideas.

Answer (score 2):

> Pictograms

A pictorial symbol for a word or phrase. Pictographs were used as the earliest known form of writing, examples having been discovered in Egypt and Mesopotamia from before 3000 BC.

---

Note: The answer given by @vickyace is still technically correct as pictograms, or pictographs, are a form of ideographs/ideograms.

Comment: The blurb of Book from the Ground, composed entirely in emoticons and punctuation, reads: "Xu Bing spent seven years gathering materials, experimenting, revising, and arranging thousands of pictograms to construct this narrative." https://books.google.com/books/about/Book_from_the_Ground.html?id=mAEZngEACAAJ&hl=en